# Multi-AND circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I want to build a circuit with multi AND logic which may trigger different LED by different combination of switch

Here is my thought:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvor4X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So when I press `1,2,4` it will trigger one LED and `1,3,4` for another
But I don't know how to achieve this since it might trigger both LED with those combination

So how can I have different switch combination to trigger different LED but with same switches?

Comment: Press sw2 and sw5 means both lights on, 3 and 4 no function

Comment: You press 1,2,4 ... Where is 1?

Comment: Oops sorry plus one to all the numbers to match the switch

Comment: The polarity of your battery is reversed. If it is not a typo, when you apply the voltage to the LEDs you could fry them. Most common LEDs have a max reverse voltage of about 6V~8V.

Comment: You should edit the question, not fix it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

> So when I press 1,2,4 it will trigger one LED and 1,3,4 for another

This circuit should do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDDF6D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How about if I also want to achieve 1,2,3?

Comment: @AndrewYoung that is different question. Here I gave you answer to original question. It is unclear what you want to achieve. I would use microcontroller for more complex combinations.